# Get all current forms via code

Tags: ranorex

I can identify (find) an element with a certain RanoreXPath via Ranorex Spy, but not via Ranorex API.
Is there a method to output all current \forms on the computer to be able to debug the problem?

Comment: Please give the xPath that works through Ranorex Spy and the code part where you are trying to find the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var FormElementList = Host.Local.Find("/form");

foreach (var formElement in FormElementList) {
    Report.Info(formElement.GetPath(PathBuildMode.Default, Ranorex.Host.Local).ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By *identify*, do you really mean *find*?

When I encouter problems with troubleshooting an issue, I usually insert **Report.Screenshot** and **Report.Snapshot** at strategic places in recordings (or user code).

When **Report.Screenshot** has no element specified, it captures a screenshot of the entire desktop which can be useful (when tests are executed unattended).
**Report.Snapshot** does however need an element (/form could be used as suggested by RanorexPro), but if your XPath is incorrect, this won't help much...

Hoping this gives you ideas...